# JavaScript JSON.parse returning array property as undefined

Tags: javascript, json, string

The real problem here is not an undefined property, but I am not being able to find out why. It is a large JSON string pended by a PHP, it contains a file list, subdirectories list, etc. and some extra information in an Object called Mt. This Mt has some properties, some strings, objects and two arrays, both of them are undefined!

The Mt JSON string:

```
    {
    "Mt": {
        "About": "Dublin Core Metadata Based, project DC+, version 1.0",
        "Name": "AlgunsEBooks",
        "Version": "1.0",
        "FileExtension": "mt",
        "Fields": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        "IndexedFields": [1, 2],
        "FieldKey": "1",
        "StringEncoding": {
            "Text": "URI",
            "Code": "none",
            "Date": "none",
            "RasterImage": "Base64",
            "VectorImage": "Base64"
        },
        "DescriptionFieldsBasic": {
            "previousFileName": "String",
            "previousFileTime": "String",
            "icone": "String-RasterImage",
            "orelha": "String"
        },
        "DescriptionFieldsExtras": {
            "obs": "String"
        },
        "DescriptionType": "Object",
        "IncludedFilesMasc": "{base}.{ext}",
        "IncludedFilesFields": {
            "base": "{base}",
            "ext": "pdf|epub|jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

I did validate it through jsonlint.com. By using JSON.parse it will turn into an Object perfectly. But when I receive the same string after a request to a PHP (that performs the file listing and generates the JSON), won't work. Both "Fields" and "IndexedFields" properties are undefined.

The returned string from the xmlhttprequest possibly contains some character that is invalidating the JSON in those particular points, but when I print the string through console.log, the string I got is a valid one. I tried to copy the string printed by console.log and to perform JSON.parse in a separated testing code and it works, so the string printed is not all contents of the var, though.
I also tried to save the PHP answer into a file and the result is a valid string again, the problem seams to be the string returned by the xmlhttprequest event when it is loaded. The error must be inside the var, but I can't see it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use an a try catch for validate if the JSON is complete or not. Also, I will recommend you that send thought PHP some values that help you identificate when the value of any property of you builded JSON is null or fill with a 0 or any bool value.

Comment: The JSON is not generating error to be catch, just parsing an array as undefined, but I will try it anyway. Also, the idea of passing codes to see if will generate error is a good idea, I will try it too.

Comment: How do you check if `Fields` and `IndexedFields` are `undefined`?

Comment: When I print the object by console.log, those properties are undefined. I do this procedure in order to compare with the separate testing code results.

Answer (score 0):

My question was downvoted, so people might not be interested and will not post any answers, so instead of call for somebody to do is, I will do it myself.

There is an answer really, and a very important one!

Following Fernando Urban advices, I started to send other values to Fields and IndexedFields to see what happens, the result was always undefined. So I changed the name Fields to StrangeThings all the way of the process. So StrangeThings resulted the array I was expecting - perfect! But the object still had Fields:undefined, than I started to search for a source of this property before the point the object is printed by console.log, there isn't one. Fields is created by nothing? Finally I recall that I already had this kind of trouble before many years ago when working with Flash - AS3:

The console is showing a value that is created AFTER it's own line. Below the console.log there is two functions that process those arrays (these arrays are numbers that will be associated to another array). Those functions were with type error and the result is undefined (will deal with this later). Once I removed those lines, Fields disappeared and IndexedFields returned the array expected.

So in some situations we have to consider a non-linear execution when debugging. I tested in Safari, Firefox and Chrome, it is a standard, but I don't have further information - if you have, please contribute!

Comment: So you mean you did log the whole parsed object and then check in your console's live-view the values inside this object ? If so, yes it is normal. If you want to see the actual value, you need to log the key/value pair you're interested in, or log a clone of your object.

Comment: It's normal but unusual. I wish to leave this case as a warning that just log the object does not guarantee to find the exactly point.

Comment: But there is like no chances that anyone experiencing the same issue in the future (`console.log(object)` => live representation of 'object') will come to **your** Q/A. Nothing in the body of the question relates to this, and even your answer is not clear.

Comment: I was thinking about this, the title is about a situation with many reasons. On the other hand, bad JSON parsing is a common glitch... In my opinion, we should let it anyway, who knows, but if the community thinks otherwise, we might delete it. I just though as I solved my problem, other ones might find it useful.